# Using last part of command for next command

Tags: command-line, history

When using the command I know a friend of mine who used to re-use last part of previous command. He unfortunately moved far away and I can't get hold of him.

**First:**

```
cp -r folder ~/folder
```

Then he was re-using **~/folder** in a very quick way.

Anyone who knows how to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The variable `$_` is used to substitute the most recent parameter.

So, in the example you mentioned, you'd do something like:

```
cp -r folder ~/folder
cd $_
```

`cd $_` will change directory to the most recent parameter i.e. `~/folder`.

For more such variables, have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/5163260/1626345.

Comment: beautiful if you ask me

Comment: Is there any difference between `$_` and `!$`?

Comment: No, normally, they function the same.

Answer (score 4):

With the arrow up key you can quickly access the last command you used.

With Ctrl+R you can do a 'reverse-i-search'. That means you just type in any letter or word of a command you already used and it will show up when enough identifying input is given.

Typing `!$` will insert **the last word** (or **a whole path** if it's one) of the last command you used. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68372/what-is-your-single-most-favorite-command-line-trick-using-bash) for a lot of useful tips. I just bookmarked it. :)

If you are planning to do this quite often with the same paths, [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31161/quick-directory-navigation-in-the-terminal) tutorial might help.